# Assigning specific return value from multiple return values to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query whoes result I is saved in a variable named @return:

```
SELECT @return = THM.NAME
FROM Theme THM
LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber
    AND (
        THM.NAME = 'Adaptive'
        OR THM.NAME = 'Corrective'
        OR THM.NAME = 'Perfective'
        OR THM.NAME = 'Preventive'
        OR THM.NAME = 'New Development'
        )
```

There are instances where more than one from my list would be returned in a normal query where the result is not getting assigned to a variable. In this case I would like 'New Development' to have lowest presedent. That is, if any of the other 4 (Adaptive, Corrective, Perfective, Preventive)are returned as well as 'New Development' one of the 4 is what will be assigned to the variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have priority indication in your table to make `New Development` the lowest?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: I posted an example with how a reference table should be used! Hope it helps. Performance wise, that is the best option, also you can prevent the IN or OR operations by just joining with the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit quick and dirty. An other option is working with inner queries but its less easy to write out. If you really need it I'll take some time to figure it out too.

This query will, when more than 1 result is present, return adaptive first, then corrective, then perfective, then preventive and finally new development.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @return = THM.NAME
FROM Theme THM
LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber
    AND THM.NAME IN ('Adaptive','Corrective','Perfective','Preventive','New Development')
ORDER BY 
    CASE THM.NAME WHEN 'Adaptive' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'Corrective' THEN 2
                  WHEN 'Perfective' THEN 3
                  WHEN 'Preventive' THEN 4
    ELSE 6 END
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't using inners queries be less effiecient?

Comment: No idea really... depends... But I advise using @OracleUser's solution

Answer (score 3):

Advisable to have a *PRIORITY* Table !

```
SELECT TOP 1 @return = THM.NAME
FROM Theme THM
LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS priority ,'Adaptive' as status_descr UNION ALL
           SELECT 2,'Corrective' UNION ALL
           SELECT 3,'Perfective' UNION ALL
           SELECT 4,'Preventive' UNION ALL
           SELECT 5,'New Development') AS MYPRIORITY
  ON(MYPRIORITY.status_descr = THM.NAME)
WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber
ORDER BY MYPRIORITY.priority ASC
```

Comment: Nice idea. You could even go further and create a real table where you can manage your 'priorities'.